# How can I use regex to select a string between two nth occurences of a character in a long string?

Tags: regex

I am using a web scraper to gather data (webscraper.io) and within that there is a regex filter that I want to use to extract text from long, unruly text blocks broken up by special characters. How do I use regex in a general way to select text between, for example, the first and second occurrence of a given character (then second and third, then third and fourth, and so on)? I am just looking to set one up then manually modify the "nth occurrence" qualifier.

I have text blocks that basically look like this:

● First line of text

● Second line of text

● Third line of text

● Fourth line of text

I tried to use something like /(?:[^●]*●)[^●]*

But that selects everything.
What would I have to add or change (maybe the whole thing because I am not good at regex) so I can select "First line of text"? I can then use a separate regex lines for "Second line of text" and so on. One line/filter for each selection.

I am just looking for a general template that I can modify to select the different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to find nth match. However, if you want to match the text between nth and (n+1)th pattern, you could try lookahead and lookbehind.

```
(?<=Q).*?(?=Q)
```

This regex match text between two capital 'Q'. `(?<=Q)` checks if there's a Q before the text, and `(?=Q)` checks if there's one after.

https://regex101.com/r/9RzuxN/1/
For example, it will yield 3 matches for `123QmatchedQitem2Qitem3Qfour`: `matched`, `item2` and `item3`

If you want to match each line of regex, `.` does not match newlines by default in most language. So, `^.*$` match each line.
https://regex101.com/r/9RzuxN/2